# Does numpy array subtraction change the dimensions when a 1-D is subtracted by a 2-D?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am implementing a rbf kernel on python using Numpy, and I could not understand why a numpy array X with shape (7,) subtracted by a numpy matrix Y with shape (5,7) will return a numpy matrix of size (5,7).

By looking at the dimensions, I thought it was something impossible because you couldn't even reshape (7,) into (5,7). So I'd like to know whats going on in the background when a numpy array is subtracted by a numpy matrix.

My idea is numpy reshaped X into (1,7), then constructed a (5,7) matrix through concatenating 5 of the reshaped X. Don't know if this is right...

Would appreciate if someone can give some insight!
Thanks!

Comment: This is called broadcasting. See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: Through the magic of `strides` it is doing exactly that, but more efficiently.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the documentation on broadcasting really helped.